# Asyncio sockets reader returns empty bytes

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-sockets

I'm trying to write a simple crawler. But trying to read the response from the server returns the answer only the first time. Then the reader stops reading bytes and returns b''.
I tried to put a timeout and use drain() after writing. It has not produced results. Wireshark shows that the answers come from the server, but my program does not see them.

```
import asyncio

HOST = '93.184.216.34'
PORT = 80
CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS = 3

request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' \
          'Host: example.com\r\n' \
          'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' \
          '\r\n'.encode()


async def smart_read(reader):
    buffer = b''
    while True:
        response = await reader.read(1024)
        if not response:
            break
        buffer += response
    return buffer


async def work(host, port, request):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    while True:
        writer.write(request)
        resp = await smart_read(reader)
        print(resp)


tasks = []
for _ in range(CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS):
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(work(HOST, PORT, request)))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `while True` loop in `work`? Remove it and test

Comment: Crawler will send many requests in a single connection . This is done for example. In the original code, I use Queue for links transmission.

Comment: Consider using [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/) for crawling the web.

Comment: example of crawler is even in asyncio examples https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/examples/crawl.py

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But why my code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Once [StreamReader](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/streams.py#L330) reaches EOF, you will always get `b''`, you can clear `_eof` flag in reader, but it's hacky. Subclassing StreamReader to handle many requests, seems to be reasonable solution.

Quick 'n' dirty (really do not use it)

```
async def work(host, port, request):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    while True:
        reader._eof = False  # force to read
        writer.write(request)
        resp = await smart_read(reader)
        print(resp)
```